# Vue.js - unwanted manipulate data reference

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

problem is i copied the value of `newEvent object` in `newEventBody` variable and i want while i call api manipulate the data in newEventBody variable and send it . with no change in newEvent property in data object! but im surprised that it change the newEvent properties every time i call api
what is the problem?

data:

```
newEvent: {
            start_time: '',
            end_time: '',
},
```

methods:

```
async createEvent() {

                let newEventBody = this.newEvent;
                newEventBody.start_time = newEventBody.start_time.split('+')[0] + 'Z';
                newEventBody.end_time = newEventBody.end_time.split('+')[0] + 'Z';
                ApiService.post(process.env.VUE_APP_EVENTS, newEventBody)
                    .then(() => {
                    })
                    .catch(err => {
                    });
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're referencing the `newEvent` by that assignment so to avoid that you could use the modern spread operator :

```
let newEventBody = {...this.newEvent};
```

Comment: i just copied the newEvent to newEventBody variable and then i changed properties in newEventBody local variable . it weird

Comment: it's an expected behavior because you're referencing the same object not cloning it, you're referring to the same memory object with different names, but with spread operator or `assign` function you're creating a new instance (copy) of that object and it's independent from the first